# dhtmlx grid - add new row and start on cell editor

Tags: javascript, grid, dhtmlx

I'd like to add a new row to my dhtmlx grid and run on-cell-editor. There are some functions provided like `selectCell` but doesn't work for me. The cell is selected but no editor is visible or triggered.

```
function addNewGridRow()
{
    // add new row with id "new" and value "New event category" as col 0 value
    editEventCategoryGrid.addRow('new','<?php echo $this->translate->_('EVT_newCategorieName'); ?>');
    // start editor on this cell
    var nameCell = editEventCategoryGrid.cells('new',0);
    nameCell.edit();
}
```

I have tried `nameCell.edit()` and the editor appears, but it won't close on `blur` like other "normal" in-cell editors. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
//add new row
editEventCategoryGrid.addRow('new','<?php echo $this->translate->_('EVT_newCategorieName'); ?>');
//select cell
editEventCategoryGrid.selectCell('new',0);
//switch selected cell to edit mode
editEventCategoryGrid.editCell();
```

Comment: thanks Aquatic - but i have the the problem, to stop the editor with this solution :) no "blur" event is registered with this manual edit call :(